# Htaccess direct linking image to page

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to prevent direct image viewing without the entire page.

If someone goes to 

mysite.com/images/image1.jpg forward to mysite.com/image1.htm

mysite.com/images/image2.jpg forward to mysite.com/image1.htm

mysite.com/images/image3.jpg forward to mysite.com/image2.htm

mysite.com/images/image4.jpg forward to mysite.com/image2.htm

Is Htaccess the best way to do this and how would I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the "Referer" request header. Browsers sometimes use it to tell the server what URL told the browser to load the file. However, not all browsers will use the referer header and it can easily be forged, so this is not a sure way to prevent direct linking to your images.

You can add this at the top of your htaccesss file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://mysite\.com/
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)\.jpg$ /$1.html [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, but different pages are specific to different images.  I want to re-direct directly to where the image came from.

Comment: @user3851589 then there's no way to do this in the htaccess file unless you make a rule for each image. Mod_rewrite has no idea what the content of your pages are.

Comment: I plan to make a rule for each image.  I only need the htaccess file in the image directory so any other rule would not apply anyways.

Comment: Is this what I need?
RewriteRule ^images/image1.jpg$ /image1.html [L,R]

Comment: @user3851589 you need a rewrite condition followed by a rule, for each of your images. The condition would be the URL to your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments, I'd recommend to avoid maintaining **N** `RewriteRule`s for **N** images. Such a setup will turn into a maintenance nightmare for the site admin who will need to copy and paste a new rule for every new image on the site. And if you ever need to change the rules, well... good luck with that.

If you have the flexibility to choose a better directory structure, it can simplify your .htaccess file down to a single rewrite rule. In that case, you can choose a directory structure where given a path to an image you can easily determine the path to the page it belongs to. For example:

```
root/
  .htaccess
  page1/
    index.html
    image/
      image1.jpg
      image2.jpg
  page2/
    index.html
    image/
      img.jpg
```

Here the rewrite definition within `root/.htaccess` is simple (adapted from @jon-lin's answer):

```
# Rewrite any image URL `/<page>/images/*` to `/<page>/`.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://mysite\.com/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/image/ /$1/ [L,R]
```

#### Pros

- One `RewriteRule` to rule them all.
- Your images do not have to be .jpg, as long as they reside in `/<page>/image/`.

#### Cons

- Need to reorganize existing files.
- Directory structure very tailored to the rewriting problem. It would be awkward for a page to access an image which "belongs" to another page.

Comment: I think we're on the right track the images have similar names to the files I'm linking to. 

The images would be 
url/subdir/images/Random123_1.jpg, url/subdir/images/Random123_2.jpg, and they would embed in url/subdir/html/Random123.htm

Comment: All of the images are in an /image/ folder and have an underscore with image number per page before the extension.

Comment: Ah okay, so with this naming scheme you'd want to change the rule to `RewriteRule ^(.+)/images/([^_]+)_ /$1/html/$2.html [L,R]`. Note that this will look for any URL like `PREFIX/images/SUFFIX_` and redirect it to `PREFIX/html/SUFFIX.html` where `PREFIX` is any string and `SUFFIX` is any string without underscores.